# Why return const reference when implement the operator= in vector class

Tags: c++, vector, reference, constants, return-type

I read it from 'Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++'. The return type of the member function `operator=` is `const Vector&`. I wonder if the vector can be modified later?

C++ Primer says we can not change a const reference, it gives this example:

```
const string& shorterString(const string& s1 , const string& s2)

shorterString("hi","bye") = "X" //wrong
```

Comment: Standard practice is to return a non-const reference from `operator=`.

Comment: What are you really asking?

Comment: if the return type is const reference,  can i modify the vector later?

Comment: Are you asking about 'vector', or 'string'?  Are you asking about 'operator=', or the behaviour of 'const'?

Comment: Maybe, but not via the returned reference. That is what `const` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `operator=` returns a non-const reference to the caller. You can see this in classes from STL, for example.
However, the return type rarely matters, because to return something from assignment is an additional effect which, for example, allows chaining:

```
a = (b = (c = d));
(a = b).callMethod();
```

`operator=` could be `void` as well, and assignment expressions couldn't be used somewhere else. But they would still work, modify its argument and leave it modifiable, i.e. non-const:

```
A a, b, c;
b = c; //call, say, void A::operator=(const A &)
a = b; //ditto
//a = b = c; //impossible here
a = c; //works
```

So, the modification of `a` has nothing to do with the return type of the assignment operator, but with its *side-effects*.

As for your second example, `shorterString` which gets two `const`-references and returns one of them, should obviously leave it `const`. And if you need to work with the result in a non-`const` way, you must use non-`const` arguments as well: `string& shorterString(string& s1, string& s2)`. These two functions can be overloads, and the compiler will choose an appropriate one.